# What is the chance that two freely rotated ends of a broken stick will intersect?

Tags: probability

Given three line segments $L1$, $L2$, and $L3$ of length $1$, give them each a random orientation chosen independently and uniformly among angles, then connect $L1$ to $L2$ and $L2$ to $L3$. What's the probability that $L1 $ intersects  $L3$

As I understand it, the largest angle at which we will intersect $L1$ and $L3$ is 60 degrees, and the smallest will be equal to 0? but most likely I don't understand which angle will be the smallest here. And as I understand it, it is better to solve this graphically

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have to define how you will connect the lines.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bertrand's paradox? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) The fewer details you give in a problem that depends on 'random' this and 'random' that, the greater the freedom anyone has to interpret the specific implementation of randomness, thereby resulting an a variety of answers to different implementations of randomness all stemming from the same (under-specified) question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions about the problem so that the problem makes sense to me.

Assume the line segments have been oriented so that L1 and L2 have one endpoint at the origin and that L3 is connected to the other end of L2 in a particular way defined below (there are other ways to define the ways of connecting, but this is one reasonable way).

Without loss of generality, assume:

- L2 has endpoints $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$
- L1 has endpoints $(0,0)$ and $(\cos{\theta_1}, \sin{\theta_1})$
- L3 has endpoints $(1,0)$ and  $(1-\cos{\theta_2}, \sin{\theta_2})$

where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are independent and identically distributed uniform on $[0,2\pi]$.

Now, for each fixed $\theta_1$, find the set of $\theta_2$ that will result in L1 intersecting L2. This is tricky.

To make it easier, just consider the case where $\theta_1<\pi$. By symmetry, the probability that L1 intersects L3 will be twice the probability that L1 intersects L3 and $\theta_1<\pi$.

For $\theta_1$ between 0 and $\pi/3$, the $\theta_2$ are those in $[\pi/2+\theta_1/2,\pi]$. For $\theta_1$ between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, the $\theta_2$ are those in $[2\theta_1,\pi]$. For other $\theta_1<\pi$, the lines segments do not intersect.

Therefore, the probability is
$$2\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/3}{\frac{\pi/2-\theta_1/2}{4\pi^2}}d\theta_1+\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}{\frac{\pi-2\theta_1}{4\pi^2}}d\theta_1\right)=\frac{1}{12}.$$

There are other ways of connecting the line segments. Some of them result in problems with trivial solutions or solutions that can be derived from the solution above (for example if all three line segments are connected at the same point). But, a harder problem is when I assume the lines are connected not at the endpoints, but at a random point in the interior of the line segments. I can only approximate the solution for this case by simulation.

Comment: The graphical solution indicates the answer must be strictly less than $1/4.$  What justifies your asymmetric treatment of the distributions of the $\theta_i$??

Comment: @whuber, you are right. It has to be less than 1/4. I have to make an assumption about how the lines are connected and I discuss now four different ways (always above x-axis, always below x-axis, randomly above or below, always to the left of line x=1). Most other assumptions I could think of made the problem trivial.

Comment: The graph suggests the solution (for all possible orientations, which I believe is your "doubled" answer) should be less than $1/8 = 0.125.$ I get $3/32=0.09375.$  I think your answer is too simple because its intersection test is incorrect.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for checking. You are right. I have the correct solution now and checked it by simulation. I will edit my answer.